# Looping in array changes element type

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

Consider this PHP code snippet which loops in array *by value reference*:

```
$arr = [1 ,2 , 3];
var_dump($arr);
echo '<br>';

foreach ($arr as &$val) { // note ampersand sign
   // Anything
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Now first var_dump() emits

> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }

But second emits

> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> &int(3) }

Thus looping in array by reference has changed last value type - from integer to integer **reference** !
How can it be at all ? Why PHP has decided itself to change element types without developer intention to do so ?

Comment: Execute `unset($val)` after `foreach`.

Comment: `$a = &$b;` makes both variables to be a reference. It is what your  foreach does - $val=$arr[0] then $val =& $arr[1]....

Comment: I know that unseting $val, or changing variable name helps. But question is not about this. WTF, why intermediate variable affects arrays element storage ? I ask for explanation of this strange behavior or maybe rationale behind this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand this behaviour, you need to understand a few things about PHP:

- References in PHP are *symmetrical*: you don't "create a reference to a variable", you "add the variable to a reference set".
- A `foreach` by reference is the same as a series of assignments by reference, one after the other.
- Array values are treated as variables in their own right, and can have all the same type information, including being part of a reference set.

So let's "unroll" your loop:

```
// create a reference set containing $val and $arr[0]
$val =& $arr[0];
// remove $val from the first reference set, 
// and create a second reference set containing $val and $arr[1]
$val =& $arr[1];
// remove $val from the second reference set, 
// and create a third reference set containing $val and $arr[2]
$val =& $arr[2];
```

At this point, `$arr[0]` and `$arr[1]` are each in a reference set of size 1, so can be seen as "normal values". However, `$arr[2]` is still in a reference set with `$val`.

What that means is that any change to `$arr[2]` will be reflected in `$val`, and any change in `$val` will be reflected in `$arr[2]`. That's why `var_dump` is annotating that item with an `&`, to show that changing it will also change another variable somewhere else.

This is why it is a good habit to always run `unset($val);` after using a foreach-by-reference.